# Issue with MLflow Model Registry in Airflow Docker Compose

Tags: python, docker, airflow, mlflow

I'm trying to integrate Airflow and MLflow using Docker Compose. The pipeline is working fine!  ML FLow tracks also the parameters and metrics. However, when I try to view the registered models, I encounter the following error:

**INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Model registry functionality is unavailable; got unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry data storage. Supported URI schemes are: ['postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']. See https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage for how to run an MLflow server against one of the supported backend storage locations.**

Docker Compose:

```
....
services:

  mlflow:
    build:
      dockerfile: docker_mlflow/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 600:600
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      # yamllint disable rule:line-length
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      ( SOME STUFF )

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Thanks in advance!

Tried also to make a bridge and volumes

Answer (score 1):

The solution would depend on what you have as the CMD or ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile.  The key part is the `--backend-store-uri`. As a test you can change it in docker-compose.override.yml with something like this:

```
  mlflow:
    image: ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow
    command:
    - bash 
    - -c
    - '(pip install -q boto3) && (mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --backend-store-uri sqlite:////data/mlflow_backend.db --default-artifact-root s3://mlflow-data)'
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    volumes:
    - ${PWD}/include/mlflow/data:/data
    networks:
      - airflow
```

The pip install of boto3 is only needed if you want to use s3 for the artefact store.   The above is an example of the [Scenario 5: MLflow Tracking Server enabled with proxied artifact storage access](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-5-mlflow-tracking-server-enabled-with-proxied-artifact-storage-access) which works well with Airflow.  You could run a local minio for the artefact store as with something like:

```
minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    command:
    - server 
    - /data 
    - --console-address 
    - ":9001"
    ports:
    - 9000:9000
    - 9001:9001
    networks:
      - airflow
```

Some examples are available at:
https://github.com/astronomer/use-case-mlflow
https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-llm-demo

Comment: Also I don't think that port 600 will work here.